# How do I 'build an object' in typescript without ignoring types

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

Hi I'm struggling to do a common javascript pattern in typescript without resorting to using `any` to ignore the types. I'm trying to write a function that builds an object depending on some conditions, giving the correct return type. I've boiled it down to the following example:

Is it possible to get the following function to work without using `any`?

```js
function hasAB<A extends boolean, B extends boolean>(shouldHaveA: A, shouldHaveB: B): HasAB<A, B> {
    const obj: any = {}
    if (shouldHaveA) obj.a = ""
    if (shouldHaveB) obj.b = ""
    return obj
}
type HasAB<A extends boolean, B extends boolean> = 
    (A extends true ? {a: string} : {}) &
    (B extends true ? {b: string} : {}) 

const a = hasAB(true, false)
const b = hasAB(false, true)
const ab = hasAB(true, true)
```

The return types are correct for a, b, and ab, however the compiler doesn't check the code. You could set `obj.a` twice and it wouldn't care.

[See code in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.2#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgBYEMDOBBAQgHm2QFMAPGYiAE02QCMEEAbY9CAGmVxPMpvsYs2APgAUmVAjBMqACXQA3YtgBcybJwlSZ8pbjW4AlGvk4CGrsOQBvYMnvIoSTDGQI6AKzVsAnsgC8NgC%20dg5wIMjiktJyisqGbp4AdOgByABE6aH24ZFaMbrERokeSXRpmdnIAE7EMGDVKO4ewCEwPgAOxMimeIQ8FNS0DMysHFwDfMOCY1aBVaJEZIP8MNVg3QD8NuhqLtVwEADmQchq1kEJAGQL3MtTyGsbyNvWdHtrhydnwQnAwE4IC5kKlAhgzKInsROCB0ExMMRDADnK5ymCsHhRLD4dDHutEciga50Gi0BjcJD8ZwoUjgAB6OkgmAUAC2HVcAEYQdRkAAmZCwuDw%20jEKDoMAI5CHEDEWrQbowdAAa2ItBgqG6kEQTQigKocHgSDhtGISSOSUJwJAcCUaShL2QAFYfgAWADcyAZAptxDUzoAPsgXaBILBtUzWeyOf17kMBKM2Jw7rw4yMhBAxPkdHFVOpNNFs3oDMYeuTCEmrLYHDU6g0UFXqw4ks2otpYkoiK8QWpMshTudLuwqtXm0lWwU4twu%208Muk%20z8LkjqyEQuBoIaUOhmcQ2TBeTGU-w02Mk5NUzMROPC8o1BYs%202isWTGWLLhK1VAcDmlzAvfCp2dh7dJ%202CD8URKflfwLB8pxsUdv04GdMhA78qlqepGggt1Wn%20L0t0jVwAGZHDYAByVwjjqNwlGqR4NTQBoqBYNwIggYhiH1Y5HgQEFMEwOAjk3FBDngOFHk6YgQ3XcN8J3dlCIPFZpgTcZkyU%20N00zaD-1vfM20KfQuBLXpzArGwqhYVxmjSC4qlyK8H2wBIG0bEobOQeDPE4XZZz7KoQmrey-0nZzhwcazAmsDzm2aRCgL85c0NrTDmhwvDt13IMBXQIU1UYKSwyQCM5JgF1FIeY9EwmWMjwvDMHJ0vNkGCosjOfMxy0sczAoiBqc1C1z7E-YkbJ85D-Ls3qWqKAbBuG%20gbNHURUn9QNFzi2cAocLahvA60IDEwJylW0Dq3QutvQOpgcP%20IA)

Here are my attempts:

```js
// attempt 1 and 2 fails because inference takes the union of conditionals e.g.
const five = true ? 5 : 4; // five: 5 | 4
function attempt1<A extends boolean, B extends boolean>(shouldHaveA: A, shouldHaveB: B): HasAB<A, B> {
    return {
        ...(shouldHaveA ? { a: "" } : {}),
        ...(shouldHaveB ? { b: "" } : {})
    }
}
function attempt2<A extends boolean, B extends boolean>(shouldHaveA: A, shouldHaveB: B): HasAB<A, B> {
    const obj1 = shouldHaveA ? {a: ""} : {}
    const obj2 = shouldHaveB ? {...obj1, b: ""} : obj1
    return obj2;
}

// attempt 3 can't get over the hurdle of needing to assign an intial type
function attempt3<A extends boolean, B extends boolean>(shouldHaveA: A, shouldHaveB: B): HasAB<A, B> {
    let obj = {}
    if (shouldHaveA) {
        obj = { ...obj, a: "" }
    }
    if (shouldHaveB) {
        obj = { ...obj, b: "" }
    }
    return obj
}
// attempt 4 fails too
function attempt4<A extends boolean, B extends boolean>(shouldHaveA: A, shouldHaveB: B): HasAB<A, B> {
    if (shouldHaveA) {
        const a = {a: ""}
    }
    if (shouldHaveB) {
        const b = {...(a || {}), b: ""}
    }
    const final = b || {}
    return final
}
// attempt 5 fails because ternary always assumes a union
function hasAB<A extends boolean, B extends boolean>(shouldHaveA: A, shouldHaveB: B): HasAB<A, B> {
    const obj = {}
    const withA: A extends true ? {a: string} : typeof obj = shouldHaveA ? {a: ""} : obj
    const withB: withA & (B extends true ? {a: string} : {}) = shouldHaveB ? {...withA, b: ""} : withA
    return withB
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript can't do this yet. The best way forward was to make use of what typing there is e.g. checking spelling mistakes in the object without guaranteeing the shape of the end result.